# ASP.NET MVC: Redundant (strongly typed) views in CRUD areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the CRUD areas of my MVC app I have lots of seemingly pointless view files, such as:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Some.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SomeModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="ContentID" ContentPlaceHolderID="SomePlaceHolder" runat="server">
   <%= Html.DisplayForModel() %>
</asp:Content>
```

This is of course pretty unDRY.

**Is it possible to use a shared view for this while at the same time preserving the Strong Typing?** (e.g. by specifying the generic type in the controller?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a display view for each CRUD controller you can have a single Display.aspx in /Views/Shared/.  The view engine searches /Views/{yourcontroller} and then /Views/Shared/ for whatever its looking for.

If all your view is <%= Html.DisplayForModel() %> then there is no need for strongly typing.  DisplayForModel() knows how to figure that out.

FOr more information on this technique:
http://haacked.com/archive/2009/08/04/default-templated-views.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If it is pretty common you could place this code in the master file (`Html.DisplayForModel()`) so that you don't need to override it in each view. And only for the views that don't need this common behavior you could override it.

Comment: But then I'm still left with the strongly typed view stubs I think.  How to get rid of those?

Comment: You could create a shared view which your controller actions will `return View("~/Views/Shared/SomeSharedView.aspx", someModel);`

Comment: But I suppose you loose the strong typing then?  Perhaps it doesn't matter...?

Comment: The strong typing makes sense only when you are working with a specific view and a specific view model. If you have common functionality such as `Html.EditorForModel` and `Html.DisplayForModel` you could easily put this inside the master page.